# mssql_connect() change default database

Tags: php, sql-server

When I connect to SQL Server 2005 database, it automatically loads the default database. I can't seem to find documentation on loading a different database with the same credentials given of course the user has access rights.

I believe this is what is occurring because I added a user with an alternate default database and received the expected results. (Problem resolved, but I wanted to know if there is a way to change the default db for future reference). I'm using SQL Server Authentication, if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting an error about the default database? or you just want to change the DB context of the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-select-db.php

Comment: I feel silly now. Thank you. I'll try to be more thorough in my searches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not call mssql_select_db giving it the link identifier returned by mssql_connect? This should preserve the credentials used to open the connection. I cannot see a way to alter the 'default' database in the PHP documentation.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I think you both answered at the same time, but I went with Femi's since the link provides further documentation.